# I have a simple regular expression which works in one case but doesnt in another

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

```
console.log(/j/i.test(undefined)); >> false
console.log(/i/i.test(undefined)); >> true
```

/i/i is regular expression to test i in passed string which not defined(undefined)

Comment: undefined or any other is treated as string when it was passed as param in test function.

Comment: But how come it output is true for "i" and false for  "j" ?

Comment: because `j` not in `undefined` but `i` in `undefined` :-)

Comment: Thanks a lot..........................................

I was scratching my head from morning

Comment: how i know means someone asked the same question like this before.

Comment: Either by searching or the person while creating question he gets the suggestion for similar question.